# Is there a way to check big directories on HD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-space

Currently on my C drive I have this weird situation

[image]

and **I can't get what file / files / directory is filling the HD space** up as I have nothing installed on C that could get that high space

maybe a Virtual Image from VMWare but **I wanted to have a software that would tell me** where my HD space is by directory...

Is there any kinda tool to help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at **TreeSize** Free here: http://www.jam-software.de/freeware/

Or **WinDirStat** here: http://windirstat.info/

There are many more tools out there, even FileMenuTools has one:
http://www.lopesoft.com/en/fmtools/info.html

**PerfectDisk** is also capable of listing the disk usage on a per directory basis:
http://www.perfectdisk.com/products/home-perfectdisk11-professional/learn-more

*Additions*

**FolderSize** is another freeware: http://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html

**SequoiaView** is a tool inspired by WinDirStat and such: http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/

**Scanner** has a different display approach:
http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/

When it comes to displaying folder size in the status bar, the Explorer component of **ClassicShell** may help out: http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/

**RidNacs** is another tiny one I came across some time ago:
http://www.splashsoft.de/Freeware/ridnacs.html

A Java software on this topic is **JDiskReport**:
http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/

There's also a free version of **Folder Visualizer** available:
http://www.abelssoft.de/apps/foldervisualizer

---

Credits go to http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/ce998316-c210-4cdb-a38b-69be223a305f

Comment: thank you, TreeSize was exactly what I wanted... takes a while but it provided very useful information :) http://bit.ly/cYAH7D

Comment: I love WinDirStat myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, none integrate with the native windows size column

Comment: @Lord - That would be really resource expensive and also would need some messing around with the explorer.. which is not acceptable.

Comment: @Lord, @Shiki: Maybe that's the reason why MS changed the API, so that in general useful tools like folder size (http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/) do not work anymore.

Comment: I use and recommend FolderSize, but as said it does not function with Vista...

Comment: An oldie that I use is the original SpaceMonger http://www.sixty-five.cc/sm/v1x.php ... I find its old-fashioned non-metallic non-3D color scheme easier to read than WinDirStat.  (I'm usually more interested in *where* than *what type* of files.)

Answer (score 1):

Try xplorer² http://www.zabkat.com/x2lite.htm. It is "For all private and academic users".

Explore and use Ctrl+D to show subfolder size :)

I did not test with Vista...

Comment: I had donate for that project before and didn't even know that part :o)